# My ElevatedButton widgets do not update the variable they are supposed to for the rest of the program

Tags: flutter, button, callback, setstate

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SkillEntry extends StatefulWidget {
   const SkillEntry({super.key, required this.skll});

   final String skll;

  @override
  State<SkillEntry> createState() => _SkillEntryState();
}

class _SkillEntryState extends State<SkillEntry> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     int skillvalue = 0;

    return Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        child: Row(children: [
          const Flexible(flex: 20, child:
          TextField(decoration:(
              InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: ('Name and Skill'))),)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: PlusOne(skillvalue), child: Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: MinusOne(skillvalue), child: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1)),
          Flexible(flex: 7, child:
           Text('$skillvalue',)),
        ]));
  }
  PlusOne(skillvalue) {
    setState(() {
      skillvalue = skillvalue + 1;
      return skillvalue;
      });
  }

  MinusOne(skillvalue) {
    setState(() {
      skillvalue = skillvalue - 1;
      return skillvalue;
    });
  }
}
```

As it stands currently the buttons seemingly do nothing. I suspect that I'm getting the `skillvalue` variable into the function `PlusOne` but not properly returning it to the main program, or I might not be using `setstate` correctly. How can I solve this?

Comment: I moved skillvalue and fixed my ElevatedButton and it all works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, `skillValue` is declared in `build` method, the value will always be zero.

secondly, the way you use `ElevatedButton` is wrong, you can not use a void method return value as a parameter to `onPressed`, which means the `onPressed` always be null.

here is my demo code.

```
class SkillEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  const SkillEntry({super.key, required this.skll});

  final String skll;

  @override
  State<SkillEntry> createState() => _SkillEntryState();
}

class _SkillEntryState extends State<SkillEntry> {

  int skillvalue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    return Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        child: Row(children: [
          const Flexible(flex: 20, child:
          TextField(decoration:(
              InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: ('Name and Skill'))),)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: PlusOne, child: Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: MinusOne, child: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1)),
          Flexible(flex: 7, child:
          Text('$skillvalue',)),
        ]));
  }
  PlusOne() {
    setState(() {
      skillvalue = skillvalue + 1;
    });
  }

  MinusOne() {
    setState(() {
      skillvalue = skillvalue - 1;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `skillValue` is declared *within* your *build* method:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 int skillvalue = 0;
```

And the `build` method re-runs every `setState`. So `skillValue` will be reset to the value you set it every time you update the UI.

To solve the problem, move the `skillValue` in the `State` class:

```dart
class _SkillEntryState extends State<SkillEntry> {

    int skillvalue = 0;
    ...
```

instead of the `build` method